# If $x$ is an element of $y$ and $y$ is an element of $z$, is $x$ an element of $z$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x\in y$ and $y\in z$. Does this imply that $x\in z$?
For example: Let $y=\{A,B\}$ and $z=\{\{A,B\},C\}$.
If $x=A$, then $x\in y$. My understanding, however, is that $x$ is not an element of $z$ since $A$ is not an element of $z$.

Comment: You are correct. $z$ has a set that holds $A$, but $z$ does not hold $A$.

Comment: The really tough question is whether $x$ can be an element of $x$ ...

Answer (score 8):

That's correct, though it can still potentially be true: \begin{align} x&=A\\
y&=\{A,B\}\\
z&=\{\{A,B\},A\}.\end{align}
So we have to know the sets completely to be sure.

Comment: Sure, by modifying the example we can make anything become true :)

Answer (score 2):

You have described the [transitive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set) of $z$.

$z$ is transitive if and only if:

> $y \in z \land x \in y \implies x \in z$

In your example, $z$ is therefore not transitive.